# infragistics gauge with tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, infragistics, gauge

I implemented an infragistics Gauge (Radial and SegmentedDigitalGauge) into a custom user control, and now I am trying to add a Tooltip and it's not working. I create a new costum control with a new Gauge and worked. Someone knows what could be wrong?

This is the code

```
ToolTip tool = new ToolTip();
tool.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
tool.InitialDelay = 1000;
tool.ReshowDelay = 500;
tool.ShowAlways = true;
tool.SetToolTip(myGauge, "ToolTip Teste");
```

The gauge is inside a TableLayoutPanel, but I think it's not the problem..

**EDIT**

I discovered that the problem is not the ToolTip itself, but it happens when I add the gauge inside an ExpandableGroupBox. Otherwise it works properly. I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I solved my problem using the UltraTooltipManager instead of TolTip. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the Radial gauge itself is a public property of the user control, you can set the tooltip text directly using the gauge control's ToolTipText property, otherwise you'll need to create a method to set said property.

[Radial Gauge Documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2014.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinRadialMenu.v14.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinRadialMenu.RadialMenuNumericGaugeTool_members.html)

For the Segmented gauge, it looks like you'll have to get the underlying gauge control from the GaugeComponent property, and then set the tooltip there.

[Segmented Gauge Documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2014.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGauge.v14.1~Infragistics.UltraGauge.Resources.SegmentedDigitalGauge_members.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have this property.. maybe my infragistics need an update!